# How to get around Eclipse swallowing double quotes for ${selected_text}

Tags: eclipse

I am using `Eclipse 3.6.1 Build id: M20100909-0800` and `Aptana Studio 2.0.5` which is based on `Eclipse 3.5.2` (both on OS X) and in both programs the external tools feature seems to swallow double quotes and whitespace for the `${selected_text}` variable.

Isn't the `${selected_text}` variable essentially useless with the mentioned behaviour?
Is there a way around that or maybe a hidden setting somewhere?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be considered a safety/security feature.

I suggest `"${selected_text}"`.

...but if it's eating ALL whitespace, that won't really help.  Huh.  Maybe it's clever enough to detect the quotes and preserve the whitespace... but probably not.

---

Okay, I did a little poking around.  Quotes within the argument list itself are preserved, as per my initial suggestion above.  I found the following auto-generated argument list that was working Just Fine:

> -os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl} -consoleLog
>   -debug "${workspace_loc:/com.cardiff.bpm.ide.webforms.ui/debug.options}"

But if your text selection contains quotes, I'd expect it to be handled as per the underlying OS.  Windows "cmd" does some... creative things with them for example.  My *nix-fu is Not Mighty, so I couldn't tell you what OS X will do under the covers, but I suspect that's where you'll find your solution.

You may have to do something goofy like URL-encode your selection, and use some command line tool to un-encode it before passing it to your desired external tool once the text is out of Eclipse's clutches.

A (very) quick look around my 3.6.1 UI didn't turn up that would do this automagically for you, but there's probably a plugin out there somewhere that'll add that feature to an editor's context (right click) menu.

I'd expect the HTML editor to have this ability already... but I don't see anything other than "smart insert mode" that sounds promising, and I don't see that working either.

---

That doth bloweth goats, most heartily, yay for weeks on end.  E'en till yon goat hath a rash, most unpleasant in both severity and locality.  Verily.

I don't think you're getting my proposed solution:

1. Set up your tool so it'll de-url-encode-ificate the incoming string with some proposed command line tool.
2. In your editor (in eclipse), URL-encode the text you wish to select and pass to the tool.  Manually.
3. Run the tool on the selected (url-encoded) text.
4. Revert the selected text.  Also manually.  Probably just "undo".

"1" is why I was looking for some eclipse UI way of url-encoding a selection.  The HTML Editor won't even do it when you paste into an attribute string.  Sheesh.

Two Other Options:

1. Fix the bug yourself.  Open Source and all that.
2. Write a plugin that exposes it's own version of ${selected_text} that doesn't strip out all the strings.
3. Hey!  SED!  Replace the quotes with some random (unused in any selection you might make) high-ascii character and sed it back to a double quote instead of the proposed de-url-encode-ificationizer.  You'd still have to manually edit/undo the text, but at least you won't have to """  Actually search/replace over a given selection makes that less painful than one might think.

I'm not sure what the scope of #2 is, but I'd image if you don't have any eclipse plugin experience the thought might be rather daunting.  There might even be a sample plugin that exposes such a variable, though I haven't checked.

---

I don't think we're communicating.

You don't select text with quotes in it.  You select mangled text, and sed demangles it back into quotes for you.

For example, you have the string `print("hello world");` in your editor and want to send that to your tool.

1. change it to `print(~hello world~);` in your editor.  Manually or via a script or whatever.
2. select it
3. run your tool, maybe wrapped in a script that'll sed the `~`s back to `"`s.
4. change it back to `print("hello world");`.

This is a manual process.  It's not pretty.  Bug workarounds are like that.  You can probably come up with a monkey script to convert quotes to Something Else, and "undo" is easy.  You might even be able to get your script attached to a keyboard short cut... dunno.  And `~` is a lousy choice for a replacement character, it's just the first thing I could think of that was rare enough to be a decent example.

Are we communicating yet?

Comment: exactly that is my dilemma: even if I wrap the variable around any combination of double or single quotes or single-, double-, triple-escaped quotes it will still eat up all double quotes in the selected text even if the selected text arrives in one piece at the external tools.

Comment: Yow.  At this point I'd say "use the source Luke!"  Eclipse is pretty good at debugging itself (in a second session).  You'll probably have to download the "with source" version of the tools plugin[s].. if they're available.  Eclipse.org plugins generally are.

Comment: Wait... are you quoting in the selection or the argument list in the tool.  Right at the bottom of the "Arguments:" section is the following text: "Note: Enclose an argument containing spaces using double-quotes (").".  If that didn't work, I'd expect folks would be bitching fairly regularly.  It'd turn up in their [bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs).

Comment: it's in the arguments section. That's why I scratched my head about this. I thought exactly the same thing as you just outlined. It's so basic it can't be that no one's noticed this. A long search revealed it is a bug that is just visible on OS X :( - http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=255619 ... since 2008 no less. There is no way around. No shell tool will help you if the quotes are swallowed before they arive at stdin. So the gist of it is simply that ${selected_text} is broken on OS X and no one cares.

Comment: Your proposed solution would be possible by something like eclipse monkey script which is just javascript and I do have scripts that are rather complex for what they do that work on the selected text BUT: you can't call any shell or command line tools from eclipse monkey. Or at least the superimposed DOM I am looking at doesn't expose a way. So then I would have url-encoded text, but no way to target any shell and therefore no direct way to shove it to my tool other than doing clipboard copy & switch to my tool & clipboard paste.

Comment: About your two other options: 1. & 2. certainly always possible I will at least take a peek to see how far I could get. 3 is not possible because sed will not see any quotes to match and replace to begin with - I can demonstrate this easily by using as  executable: /bin/echo arguments: "${selected_text}" - Let's say the selected text is: print("some python print command") - this will be printed to the Eclipse console as: print( some python print command ) - I don't know what OS you're using as you try this in your Eclipse but keep in mind that AFAIK on Windows double quotes work correctly.

Comment: No no.  Sed doesn't convert quotes-to-something-else.  It converts something-else-to-quotes.  You manually convert the quotes to that something else in your editor (maybe with a monkey script)... run your command line tool (with no quotes anywhere save what sed fed it), then convert your editor text back.

Comment: some other stuff I tried was exec: /bin/bash args: -c 'echo "${selected_text}"' which I would have piped into sed or tr or awk or whatever to get the quoting right again. But as soon as ${selected_text} is resolved into its value it will loose double quotes. So to cut it short: solutions: 1. Fix bug myself, 2. Write workaround plugin, 3. use another macro or scripting language inside Eclipse which can get at selected text and preferably can call shell commands with input and output or if not some crude manual workaround with using the clipboard to get text across processes.

Comment: Ah I think I finally got it. Yes this should work. As far as I can tell only double quotes are affected and sometimes whitespace but I can work around that by wrapping with single quotes then your something else that is converted by the monkey script which is then finally passable to whatever shell tool as ${selected_text}

Comment: Btw thanks for all the help and not to mention precious time. I am pretty sure if I split it up into two steps as proposed it should work. Then I will have to press two keyboard shortcuts to make it work - big deal I can live with that :)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I put together a patch using some guidance from a gentleman in the bug comments.

I don't know if it will be accepted, but it fixes things for me so maybe someone else may find it useful.
Again, this is only for Mac OS X Eclipse.

1. Start Eclipse.
2. Go to `Import > Plug-ins and Fragments`.

   Import From: Active Platform
   Fragments to import: Select from all plug-ins
   Import As: Projects from a repository

   `Next >`
3. Pick `org.eclipse.debug.ui` and `org.eclipse.debug.core`
4. Once the projects are in your workspace, apply the two patches that compose proposed patch v1, found at the bug tracker page for [bug 255619](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=255619)
5. Go to `Export > Deployable plug-ins and fragments` and make a jar out of your changed packages.

Hope it helps.